# Tryning to understand when and when to not use a singleton

Tags: ios, singleton

There is a lot of information about singletons, when to use it, why you shouldn't use it etc. So in hope of grasping it somewhat better maybe someone can explain it with a sample from an app I'm making.

I'm using Parse to create an app with user registration. If I use a singleton in this way, is it good or bad practice? I'm thinking that I will use my `User` class to user relevant operations throughout the app and maybe it's a good idea to create an instance of the `User` class once:

```
//  User.h

@interface User : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)createNewUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password email:(NSString*)email;

@end

// User.m

#import "User.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation User

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"sharedInstance User.m");
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)createNewUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password email:(NSString*)email {
    // Create a new user
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.password = password;

    // Additional user information
    newUser[@"email"] = email;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            NSLog(@"Success created user: %@", newUser);
        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];
}

@end

// LoginViewController.m

#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender 
{    
    [[User sharedInstance] createNewUser:self.usernameTextField.text
                                password:self.passwordTextField.text
                                   email:self.emailTextField.text];
}
```

Or is it better practice to do like this:

```
// User.h

@interface User : NSObject

- (void)createNewUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password email:(NSString*)email;

@end

// User.m

@implementation User

- (void)createNewUser:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password email:(NSString*)email {
    // Create a new user
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.password = password;

    // Additional user information
    newUser[@"email"] = email;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            NSLog(@"Success created user: %@", newUser);
        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];
}

@end

// LoginViewController.m

- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    User *newUser = [User new];

    [newUser createNewUser:self.usernameTextField.text
                  password:self.passwordTextField.text
                     email:self.emailTextField.text];
}
```

And also, if I'm misusing any of the ways please say so, I appreciate you honesty!

Comment: > "I will use my User class to make a lot of different things" - it is a  bad practice to make class to do a lot of DIFFERENT things. Check "single responsibility" principle.

Comment: Maybe that bit was a bit unclear, update that part of my question to: "I'm thinking that I will use my User class to user relevant operations"  @Avt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a temptation to make something a singleton, think this way:

- Will this class be **really** one per application **forever**? (In your cases I can see, for example, that after some time you will want administrator logging in as some user of your application and will you will end up with two user objects)
- Will this class be **really** so simple forever that I will not suffer from singleton testing and *globalistic* problems (Singletons make unit testing difficult and they add global entity to your program making it difficult to track changes to it made by various application parts)

If either of options apply to your case do something like:

- Don't make class a singleton
- Use dependency injection container or a registry pattern to bind your class to it and always resolve the class against container / registry

Comment: Thank you @FractalizeR it's starting to be a bit clearer now. So in my User class case it's not a good idea to make the User a singleton but perhaps make a class called UserManager as a singleton that may have methods like getUserId and displayUserName, or I'm i thinking wronng? Also do you have a simple example perhaps that illustrates when and when to not use singletons?

Comment: @Oskariagon I think it would be wrong to rename a class, leaving his responsibilities in place ;) UserManager could create user instances if you like. I don't see your architecture and I couldn't propose something wise enough ;)